# Prevent table-cell from increasing its width to encompass wide content

Tags: html, css, css-tables

So here's what I'm talking about:

```js
var els = document.getElementsByClassName("stuff");
for (var i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
  for (var j = 0; j < 2; ++j) {
    var el = document.createElement("div");
    el.innerHTML = i;
    els[j].appendChild(el);
  }
}
```

```css
.maintable {
  width: 300px;
}
.maincell1,
.maincell2 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
}
.maincell2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
.stuff {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  background-color: green;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.stuff div {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#fixtable {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
```

```html
<table class="maintable">
  <tr>
    <td class="maincell1">
      <div class="stuff"></div>
    </td>
    <td class="maincell2"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<table class="maintable">
  <tr>
    <td class="maincell1">
      <table id="fixtable">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div class="stuff"></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td class="maincell2"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As you can see in the snippet, the first flex div stretches out the 50% width of the cell its in. I know I could just make the main table layout fixed but I want the auto grow functionality  for another column.

To restrict the auto growing in that particular cell, in the second table I have wrapped another fixed table around the flex div and it works just the way I need.

My question is though - is there any more elegant way to do this? Since this is rather clunky...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of nested tables, you can take the flex container out of flow:

```css
.maincell1, .maincell2 {
  position: relative;
}
.stuff.fix {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

This way the contents inside the cell won't affect its width.

Note the automatic table layout is not defined by the spec, therefore the result may not be completely reliable. Reconsidering using a fixed layout might be a good idea.

```js
var els = document.getElementsByClassName("stuff");
for (var i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
  for (var j = 0; j < 2; ++j) {
    var el = document.createElement("div");
    el.innerHTML = i;
    els[j].appendChild(el);
  }
}
```

```css
.maintable {
  width: 300px;
}
.maincell1,
.maincell2 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}
.maincell2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
.stuff {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 100%;
}
.stuff div {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: green;
}
.stuff.fix {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<table class="maintable">
  <tr>
    <td class="maincell1">
      <div class="stuff"></div>
    </td>
    <td class="maincell2"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<table class="maintable">
  <tr>
    <td class="maincell1">
      <div class="stuff fix"></div>
    </td>
    <td class="maincell2"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```